# Prove that the sequence $\left(\frac{6+\cos (n^2)}{n}\right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}^*}$ approaches $0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

EDIT: Can someone let me know if this is correct now?

Prove that the sequence $\left(\frac{6+\cos (n^2)}{n}\right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}^*}$ approaches $0$. Prove directly from the definition of convergence. (Don't use the squeezing theorem.)

First of all, I had to determine by myself that it approaches $0$, so if I am incorrect about that, please let me know. Here is my formal proof thus far, which I might or might not be choosing N correctly.

Proof: Let $\varepsilon >0$. Take N = $\frac{7}{\varepsilon}.$ Since $\frac{7}{n}$ > $\left(\frac{6+\cos (n^2)}{n}\right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}^*}$

Let $n$ be a natural number. Then for $n \geq N$, we have $\left|\left(\frac{6+\cos (n^2)}{n}\right)- 0\right|$ < $\left|\frac{7}{n}\right| < \left|\frac{7}{N}\right|= \varepsilon$.

This completes the proof.

Comment: The squeeze theorem is not a "trick".

Comment: Thats just what the instructions say

Comment: I meant squeezing theorem

Comment: this has nothing to do with abstract algebra and please mathjax

Comment: Latex tips here for proper formatting of your posts: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: What is with the trend of professors requiring students to prove limits using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit -- and not allowing them to use "tricks"? First of all, they are *theorems* and not tricks, and second, the whole point of them is that going back to $\epsilon$-$\delta$ every time would be a big pain! I would be seriously tempted just to prove the "trick" as a lemma and then use it.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{6}{n}\leq \frac{6+\cos^2n}{n}\leq \frac{7}{n}
$$

Comment: The questioner asked for a solution that does not involve squeezing.

Comment: I answered before the post became legible

Comment: Excuse me - my bad.

Comment: @Furrer It's no problem! I will probably delete

Comment: @RemyM no. What happens when you take the limit on either side of the inequality?

Comment: Is my proof correct now?

Answer (score 1):

The product of a bounded sequence and a sequence with limit zero has limit zero.

Comment: (+1) even though the original question asks to do directly from $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit.

Comment: @6005 Thank you very much.  Even though I've just gave a hint, it'll be a piece of cake to get suitable deltas and epsilons from here. --